# Obrigar preenchimento de Campo Attribute C#

Tags: c#, atributos

Pessoal tenho uma classe de Attribute sendo ela:

```
 class TipoServicoAttrib : System.Attribute
{
    public TipoOperacaoEnum TipoOperacao;
    public int CodigoOperacao;
}
```

Preciso que quando eu for utilizar, seja obrigatorio o preenchimento do TipoOperacaoEnum  e do  CodigoOperacao. Existe uma forma para isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obrigatório por natureza não dá, mas ao atribuir ou declarar essa classe, você pode tornar obrigatório a utilização de parâmetros no construtor:

```cs
class TipoServicoAttrib : System.Attribute
{
    public TipoOperacaoEnum TipoOperacao;
    public int CodigoOperacao;

    public TipoServicoAttrib(TipoOperacaoEnum tipoOperacao, int codigoOperacao)
    {
        this.CodigoOperacao = codigoOperacao;
        this.TipoOperacao   = tipoOperacao;
    }

    private TipoServicoAttrib() {} // torna inacessível o construtor vazio
}
```

Assim, toda vez que `TipoServicoAttrib` for chamada, deverá ser informado estes dois valores na construção:

```cs
// OK
[TipoServicoAttrib(TipoOperacaoEnum.AlgumaCoisa, 200)]
public void OperacaoFoo() {}

// Erro
[TipoServicoAttrib]
public void OperacaoBar() {}

// Erro
[TipoServicoAttrib(TipoOperacaoEnum.AlgumaCoisa)]
public void OperacaoHello() {}
```

Como você está utilizando dois tipos não anuláveis, não é necessário verificação nula no começo do construtor. Mas se for usar um tipo que é `Nullable`, considere usar este código na primeira linha do construtor:

```
if(argumento is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(argumento));
```

Então, se o valor for nulo (e não vazio), ele irá causar um erro.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer assim, mas fica dando erro e não permite compilar o codigo

Comment: Qual o erro que dá?

Comment: estou adicionando a imagem para voce ver como está

Comment: @HimorriveL você adicionou os métodos fora da classe. Faz o seguinte, apague tudo que está dentro da `namespace` (menos ela mesmo) e coloque esse código (o primeiro da minha publicação) dentro dela (`{...}`).

Comment: que falha minha, ficou exatamente o que estava precisando, obg